# Building Turing machine graph

Tags: grammar, automata, turing-machines, automata-theory

I have been trying making a Turing machine graph recognizing the language :

`{(ab)^n(ba)^n | n >0}`

How to build the Turing machine graph for the above-mentioned language?

Answer (score 1):

1. find the substring bb by identifying two consecutive instances of b
2. cross these off by replacing with a tape symbol X
3. bounce across the section of instances of X, crossing off matching symbols in alternating fashion (first cross off matching instances of a, then b, then a, etc.)
4. halt-accept if the tape is empty after crossing off matching instances of a
5. halt-reject if you run out of symbols early or if the tape is empty after crossing out instances of b

I'll leave defining states as an exercise but if you need help with that I can revisit this answer later. As a hint - you will need either one or a couple of states to handle each of the above steps.